# How do I compile MySQL Connector C++ with MinGW-W64?

Tags: mysql, cmake, mysql-connector, mingw-w64

I am attempting to compile the MySQL Connector CPP version 8.0.20.

- Source code from https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-cpp. (Downloaded 2020-May-24)
- Following instructions at https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?117,426293,426927.

Step 3 of compiling produced the following command output:

```
e:\cpp\Lib\MySQL>cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles"
CMake Warning:
  No source or binary directory provided.  Both will be assumed to be the
  same as the current working directory, but note that this warning will
  become a fatal error in future CMake releases.

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
-- Check for working C compiler: E:/Apps/mingw-w64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: E:/Apps/mingw-w64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: E:/Apps/mingw-w64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: E:/Apps/mingw-w64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
Building version 8.0.20
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of unsigned short
-- Check size of unsigned short - done
-- Using unsigned short
-- Check if the system is big endian - little endian
-- BIG_ENDIAN: 0
Building on system: Windows-10.0.18362 (AMD64)
Using cmake generator: MinGW Makefiles
Using toolset:
Building 64bit code
Building shared connector library
Configuring CDK as part of MySQL_CONCPP project
-- Looking for SSL library.
CMake Error at cdk/cmake/DepFindSSL.cmake:79 (message):
  Cannot find appropriate system libraries for SSL.  Make sure you've
  specified a supported SSL version.  Consult the documentation for WITH_SSL
  alternatives
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cdk/cmake/DepFindSSL.cmake:346 (main)
  cdk/cmake/dependency.cmake:42 (include)
  cdk/CMakeLists.txt:96 (find_dependency)

-- Setting up Protobuf.
==== Configuring Protobuf build using cmake generator: MinGW Makefiles
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
-- Check for working C compiler: E:/Apps/mingw-w64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: E:/Apps/mingw-w64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: E:/Apps/mingw-w64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: E:/Apps/mingw-w64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of unsigned short
-- Check size of unsigned short - done
-- Using unsigned short
-- Check if the system is big endian - little endian
-- BIG_ENDIAN: 0
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
-- Found Threads: TRUE
Using pthreads for protobuf code
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: E:/cpp/Lib/MySQL/cdk/protobuf
==== Protobuf build configured.
Processor Count: 8
-- Setting up RapidJSON.
Skipping second declaration of config option: THROW_AS_ASSERT (found in: E:/cpp/Lib/MySQL/cdk/CMakeLists.txt)
-- Performing Test HAVE_STATIC_ASSERT
-- Performing Test HAVE_STATIC_ASSERT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_IS_SAME
-- Performing Test HAVE_IS_SAME - Failed
-- Check size of off64_t
-- Check size of off64_t - done
-- Looking for fseeko
-- Looking for fseeko - found
-- Looking for unistd.h
-- Looking for unistd.h - found
-- ZSTD_LEGACY_SUPPORT not defined!
-- Performing Test HAVE_SHARED_PTR
-- Performing Test HAVE_SHARED_PTR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_SYSTEM_ERROR
-- Performing Test HAVE_SYSTEM_ERROR - Success
-- Check size of wchar_t
-- Check size of wchar_t - done
-- Looking for sys/endian.h
-- Looking for sys/endian.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/byteorder.h
-- Looking for sys/byteorder.h - not found
Wrote configuration header: E:/cpp/Lib/MySQL/cdk/include/mysql/cdk/config.h
Preparing to merge SHARED library: connector (xapi;devapi)
Connector library name: mysqlcppconn8-2
Building version 8.0.20
Generating INFO_SRC
Generating INFO_BIN
Install location: C:/Users/jvines/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++
Connector libraries will be installed at: lib64

Project configuration options:

: BUILD_STATIC: OFF
Build static version of connector library

: WITH_SSL: system
Either 'system' to use system-wide OpenSSL library, or custom OpenSSL location. (default : system)

: WITH_JDBC: OFF
Whether to build a variant of connector library which implements legacy JDBC API

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "E:/cpp/Lib/MySQL/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "E:/cpp/Lib/MySQL/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Links to log files:

[CMakeOutput.log](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ptrongithub/misc/master/mysql-connector-cpp/CMakeOutput.log)

[CMakeError.log](https://github.com/ptrongithub/misc/blob/master/mysql-connector-cpp/CMakeError.log)

All files in the `/CMakeTmp` directory, referenced in [CMakeError.log](https://github.com/ptrongithub/misc/blob/master/mysql-connector-cpp/CMakeError.log), have been deleted by the script so I can't analyze them.

### Main question:

How do I fix this to finally produce the desired build files so I can move on to the next step?

#### Additional questions:

- Where does the referenced `src.cxx`, and, by extension, the `src.cxx.obj`, file come from?
- How do I eliminate the SSL error, as shown in the command output? Re:

```
-- Looking for SSL library.
CMake Error at cdk/cmake/DepFindSSL.cmake:79 (message):
  Cannot find appropriate system libraries for SSL.  Make sure you've
  specified a supported SSL version.  Consult the documentation for WITH_SSL
  alternatives
```

---

## UPDATE #1

Now using MSYS2 with MinGW-w64. The missing SSL error is eliminated.

New error at the Make step:

```
e:\cpp\Lib\MySQL\src> make
MAKE Version 5.41  Copyright (c) 1987, 2014 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
Error makefile 11: Colon expected
*** 1 errors during make ***
```

`make` command replaced with `mingw32-make` produced new errors. This post is getting long, Please follow the link for the full text of the output.

New command [output](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ptrongithub/misc/master/mysql-connector-cpp/mingw32-make_output).

There is no `mysql_ps_resultset.cpp` to edit, as referenced in Step 4.

Comment: The error message refers to that documentation about `WITH_SSL` option: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/source-configuration-options.html#option_cmake_with_ssl. Do you have SSL installed on your machine?

Comment: I have switched to using MSYS2, so SSL is definitely present, as well as Boost, which was requested by a previous version of the Connector.

Comment: Your new output tells that you have two **conflicting include directories**: `E:/Apps/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.1.0` and `E:/Apps/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/`. Something wrong with your environment, CMake parameters (e.g. generator) or a compiler.

Comment: The following packages are installed, using `pacman -S package`: `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc`, `mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake`, `mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb`, `mingw-w64-x86_64-make`, and `mingw-w64-x86_64-boost`

Comment: You have Embarcadero make in your path before GNU make.
Either fix that or try with `mingw32-make`.