# Errors when Linking mySQL C++ Connector to my Project (Windows)

Tags: c++, mysql

I'm trying to make a basic program to connect to my mySQL database in C++. I downloaded the mySQL C++ connector, added the path to the libraries with -L (Connector C++ 8.0\lib64), added the name of the library with -l (mysqlcppconn8-2-vs14), and added the include path (Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc) with -I. I wrote a few lines to connect to my database:

```
#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include "mysql_driver.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

using namespace sql;

int main() {
    try{
        Driver* driver { get_driver_instance() };

        Connection* con { driver->connect("tcp://localhost:3306", "root", "") };
        Statement* statement { con->createStatement() };
        ResultSet* res = statement->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM test.testdb");
    }
    catch(std::exception &e) {
        std::cout << "ERROR" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

But when I compile the program, I get a load of errors consistent with me not linking libraries correctly:

```
C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/include/jdbc/cppconn/driver.h:77: undefined reference to `check(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/include/jdbc/cppconn/driver.h:78: undefined reference to `check(std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > const&)'
src\main.o: In function `get_driver_instance_by_name':
C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/include/jdbc/cppconn/driver.h:90: undefined reference to `_get_driver_instance_by_name'
src\main.o: In function `get_driver_instance_by_name':
C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/include/jdbc/mysql_driver.h:106: undefined reference to `sql::mysql::_get_driver_instance_by_name(char const*)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

13:53:03 Build Failed. 4 errors, 15 warnings. (took 839ms)
```

Am I forgetting to include a library? I'm on Windows using MinGW with Eclipse.

Comment: `mysqlcppconn8-2-vs14` is for `msvc` not mingw. This may be part of the problem.

Comment: @drescherjm good call, any workaround to support MinGW you're aware of?

Comment: Related but unsolved: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62007678/how-do-i-compile-mysql-connector-c-with-mingw-w64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62007678/how-do-i-compile-mysql-connector-c-with-mingw-w64)