# C++ Error when trying to connect to Mysql server using Connector C++ 8.0

Tags: c++, mysql, cmake, clion

I'm new to C++, I want to connect to a MySQL/MariaDB database. To do that I have the following code:

```
#include <mysql_connection.h>
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

int main() {
    sql::Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *con;
    driver = get_driver_instance();
    con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "");
    delete con;
    
    return 0;
}
```

My Cmake script looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(patil_clustering_c)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySQL\\Connector C++ 8.0")

add_executable(patil_clustering_c main.cpp)

# Add the MySQL include directories to this target.
target_include_directories(patil_clustering_c PRIVATE
        ${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/include/jdbc
        )
target_include_directories(patil_clustering_c PRIVATE
        ${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/include/jdbc/cppconn
        )

# Link the MySQL library to your executable.
target_link_libraries(patil_clustering_c PRIVATE
        ${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/lib/vs14/mysqlcppconn8.lib
        )
```

When I try to run the program I get the following error:

```
====================[ Build | patil_clustering_c | Debug ]======================
C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\CLion\ch-0\223.8836.42\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe --build C:\Users\danie\Documents\projecten\patil-clustering-c\cmake-build-debug --target patil_clustering_c -j 9
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/patil_clustering_c.dir/main.cpp.obj
[2/2] Linking CXX executable patil_clustering_c.exe
FAILED: patil_clustering_c.exe 
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\CLion\ch-0\223.8836.42\bin\mingw\bin\g++.exe -g  CMakeFiles/patil_clustering_c.dir/main.cpp.obj -o patil_clustering_c.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libpatil_clustering_c.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  "C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/lib/vs14/mysqlcppconn8.lib"  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\CLion\ch-0\223.8836.42\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/patil_clustering_c.dir/main.cpp.obj:C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/include/jdbc/cppconn/driver.h:82: undefined reference to `check(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\CLion\ch-0\223.8836.42\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/patil_clustering_c.dir/main.cpp.obj: in function `check_lib':
C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/include/jdbc/cppconn/driver.h:83: undefined reference to `check(std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > const&)'
C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\CLion\ch-0\223.8836.42\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/patil_clustering_c.dir/main.cpp.obj:C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/include/jdbc/cppconn/driver.h:95: undefined reference to `_get_driver_instance_by_name'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this error?

Comment: `${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/lib/vs14/mysqlcppconn8.lib` library is for Microsoft's msvc compiler and not for MinGW.

Comment: It does look like it's a valid path for my connector (If I go to the path I see the file), what's the difference between the compilers and what should I change?

Comment: `vs14`  means that it's compiled for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015. This is not a MinGW binary. You will have incompatibilities trying to link the wrong binaries across different c++ compilers.

Comment: That's interesting, I don't think the MySQL installer has an option for what thing it should compile for, How can I get the right version?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62007678/how-do-i-compile-mysql-connector-c-with-mingw-w64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62007678/how-do-i-compile-mysql-connector-c-with-mingw-w64)